# Spark dataframe checking equality and filtering

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do I filter column with particular value?

This works fine `>`

```
scala> dataframe.filter("postalCode > 900").count()
```

but `==` fails

```
scala> dataframe.filter("postalCode == 900").count()
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.13] failure: identifier expected

postalCode == 900 ##Error line
```

I know I am missing something obvious but I cant figure out. I checked [API doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) and SO for same. Also, tried giving `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression string you pass to `filter` / `where` should be a valid SQL expression. It means you have to use a single equal operator:

```scala
dataframe.filter("postalCode = 900")
```

And example

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("foo", 900), ("bar", 100))).toDF("k", "postalCode")
df.where("postalCode = 900").show

// +---+----------+
// |  k|postalCode|
// +---+----------+
// |foo|       900|
// +---+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

In `python` it may be approached this way (using @zero323 data):

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
    [("foo", 900), ("bar", 100)]), 
    StructType([
        StructField("k", StringType(), True), 
        StructField("v", IntegerType(), True)
    ])
)

filtered_df = df.where(df.v == 900)
filtered_df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `"==="` operator with filter/where as below. basically `where` is alias of `filter`.

using the same example by zero323.

`val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("foo", 900), ("bar", 100))).toDF("k", "postalCode")`

`df.where($"postalCode" === 900).show`

`+---+----------+
|  k|postalCode|
+---+----------+
|foo|       900|
+---+----------+`

`df.filter($"postalCode" === 900).show`

`+---+----------+
|  k|postalCode|
+---+----------+
|foo|       900|
+---+----------+`

`df.filter(df("postalCode") === 900).show`

`+---+----------+
|  k|postalCode|
+---+----------+
|foo|       900|
+---+----------+`